# XamlParseException: Could not load file or assembly 'ResourceLibrary, ...' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, using, project-reference

`System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseExceptionoccurred`

`A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll`

`Additional information: 'Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an exception.' Line number '21' and line position '6'.`

`"Could not load file or assembly 'ResourceLibrary, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"ResourceLibrary, Culture=neutral"`

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = ResourceLibrary, Culture=neutral
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: ResourceLibrary, Culture=neutral | Domain ID: 2
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\QTAgent32.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/ResourceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/ResourceLibrary/ResourceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/PrivateAssemblies/ResourceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/PrivateAssemblies/ResourceLibrary/ResourceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/PublicAssemblies/ResourceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/PublicAssemblies/ResourceLibrary/ResourceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/DataCollectors/ResourceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/DataCollectors/ResourceLibrary/ResourceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/DataCollectors/x86/ResourceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/DataCollectors/x86/ResourceLibrary/ResourceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/ResourceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/ResourceLibrary/ResourceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/ResourceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/ResourceLibrary/ResourceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/ResourceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/ResourceLibrary/ResourceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/PrivateAssemblies/ResourceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/PrivateAssemblies/ResourceLibrary/ResourceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/PublicAssemblies/ResourceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/PublicAssemblies/ResourceLibrary/ResourceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/DataCollectors/ResourceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/DataCollectors/ResourceLibrary/ResourceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/DataCollectors/x86/ResourceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/DataCollectors/x86/ResourceLibrary/ResourceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/ResourceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/ResourceLibrary/ResourceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/ResourceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/projects/Autom/git/Autom/VisCong/VisConf_Tests/bin/Debug/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/ResourceLibrary/ResourceLibrary.EXE.
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @Sajeetharan, Sorry, I wasn't fast enough... look at the answer...

Comment: Why down-voting? stackoverflow.com states that it's not only a [good thing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) to answer your own question, [but it's explicitly encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This question is just a reference to myself and to whomever gets here while searching for a solution to this issue.

The `Copy Local` in the reference was set to `True` but the `DLL` was not copied to the build folder.

Since I used this resource library only in `XAML`, I had to add a `using` statement:

```
using ResourceLibrary;
```

in the referencing code (actually, the code that called the referencing code, which was either the app or the unit-test)

This made the `DLL` created in the destination build directory.

#### Edit:

Sometimes even `using ResourceLibrary` doesn't work. The solution is creating some empty static method in the code-behind of the `ResourceLibrary`:

```
namespace ResourceLibrary {
    public static class ReferencePoint {
        public static ReferToMe() {}
    }
}
```

And calling it from the referencing code:

```
ReferencePoint.ReferToMe();
```

Comment: Why down-voting? stackoverflow.com states that it's not only a [good thing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) to answer your own question, [but it's explicitly encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: This is a valid answer, I had a unit test failing with a similar exception. Simply adding the required dlls to the test project fixed the issue. Resharper would fail the test but NCrunch would pass it.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me because the app that started when I ran had a reference to a DLL in a different location that was old.

The actual project that used it had the right reference, but the starting app had the wrong one and therefore it was using that old DLL.

To solve this, I deleted the reference on the starting app and added it again to point to the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by setting the debug platform to 64 bit, same as the reference setting